# Table Partitions Cleanup

Tags: oracle, partitioning

I have a table which is partitioned on the basis of day and then hour (sub-partition).

I want to keep 10 hours of data at any given time and want to drop the earlier partitions. How to manage this when date changes? For example, to keep one partition for the first hour of 2nd August and 9 partitions of 1st August?

Any inputs will be of great help.

Table Definition is,

```
  CREATE TABLE "MY_SCHEMA"."MY_TABLE" 
   (    "TARGET_TIME" TIMESTAMP (6), 
    "TARGET_DATE" DATE, 
    "TARGET_HOUR" NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS (EXTRACT(HOUR FROM "TARGET_TIME")) VIRTUAL , 
    "MY_ID" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "MY_INDEX" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "MY_STATUS" NUMBER(10,0)
   ) PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255  NOLOGGING 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "MYTABLESPACE" 
  PARTITION BY RANGE ("TARGET_DATE") INTERVAL (INTERVAL '1' DAY) 
  SUBPARTITION BY LIST ("TARGET_HOUR") 
  SUBPARTITION TEMPLATE ( 
    SUBPARTITION "HOUR00" VALUES ( 0 ), 
    SUBPARTITION "HOUR01" VALUES ( 1 ), 
    SUBPARTITION "HOUR02" VALUES ( 2 ), 
    SUBPARTITION "HOUR03" VALUES ( 3 ), 
    SUBPARTITION "HOUR04" VALUES ( 4 ), 
    SUBPARTITION "HOUR05" VALUES ( 5 ), 
    SUBPARTITION "HOUR06" VALUES ( 6 ), 
    SUBPARTITION "HOUR07" VALUES ( 7 ), 
    SUBPARTITION "HOUR08" VALUES ( 8 ), 
    SUBPARTITION "HOUR09" VALUES ( 9 ), 
    SUBPARTITION "HOUR10" VALUES ( 10 ), 
    SUBPARTITION "HOUR11" VALUES ( 11 ), 
    SUBPARTITION "HOUR12" VALUES ( 12 ), 
    SUBPARTITION "HOUR13" VALUES ( 13 ), 
    SUBPARTITION "HOUR14" VALUES ( 14 ), 
    SUBPARTITION "HOUR15" VALUES ( 15 ), 
    SUBPARTITION "HOUR16" VALUES ( 16 ), 
    SUBPARTITION "HOUR17" VALUES ( 17 ), 
    SUBPARTITION "HOUR18" VALUES ( 18 ), 
    SUBPARTITION "HOUR19" VALUES ( 19 ), 
    SUBPARTITION "HOUR20" VALUES ( 20 ), 
    SUBPARTITION "HOUR21" VALUES ( 21 ), 
    SUBPARTITION "HOUR22" VALUES ( 22 ), 
    SUBPARTITION "HOUR23" VALUES ( 23 ) ) 
 (PARTITION "DEFAULT_20170101"  VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE(' 2017-01-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN')) 
PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "MYTABLESPACE" ) ;
```

Regards

Comment: Please provide the table definition, then I can provide you an answer.

Comment: I have added the table definition in my original question.

Comment: Do you mean "drop anything which is older than 10 hours from now"?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am looking for. If it is first hour of the day, then last 9 hours data of previous day should be present in the last day's partition. When we get 2nd hour's data for the day then previous day's partition should have 8 hours of data and so on. The whole last day's partition should be dropped only when current day has 10 hours of data

Answer (score 0):

```
PROCEDURE MaintainPartitions(givenTime IN TIMESTAMP DEFAULT LOCALTIMESTAMP) IS 

    CURSOR SubParts IS
    SELECT TABLE_NAME, PARTITION_NAME, SUBPARTITION_NAME, 
        part.HIGH_VALUE AS PART_HIGH_VALUE, 
        subpart.HIGH_VALUE as SUB_HIGH_VALUE
    FROM ALL_TAB_PARTITIONS part
        JOIN ALL_TAB_SUBPARTITIONS subpart USING (OWNER, TABLE_NAME, PARTITION_NAME)
    WHERE OWNER = 'MY_SCHEMA'
        AND TABLE_NAME = 'MY_TABLE'
    ORDER BY PARTITION_POSITION, SUBPARTITION_POSITION;

    CURSOR TabParts IS
    SELECT TABLE_NAME, PARTITION_NAME
    FROM ALL_TAB_PARTITIONS part
    WHERE OWNER = 'MY_SCHEMA'
        AND TABLE_NAME = 'MY_TABLE'
    ORDER BY PARTITION_POSITION;

    cur SYS_REFCURSOR;
    r INTEGER;
    highValue TIMESTAMP;

BEGIN
   -- Truncate old subpartitions
   FOR aSubPart IN SubParts LOOP
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN :ret := '||aSubPart.PART_HIGH_VALUE||' + INTERVAL '''||aSubPart.SUB_HIGH_VALUE||''' HOUR; END;' 
          USING OUT highValue;
      IF highValue < givenTime - INTERVAL '10' HOUR THEN
          EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE '||aSubPart.TABLE_NAME||' TRUNCATE SUBPARTITION '||aSubPart.SUBPARTITION_NAME||' UPDATE INDEXES';
      END IF;
   END LOOP;

   -- Drop empty partitions
   FOR aPart IN TabParts LOOP
       OPEN cur FOR 'SELECT ROWNUM FROM '||aPart.TABLE_NAME||' PARTITION ('||aPart.PARTITION_NAME||') WHERE ROWNUM <= 1';
       FETCH cur INTO r;
       IF cur%NOTFOUND THEN
          EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE '||aPart.TABLE_NAME||' DROP PARTITION '||aPart.PARTITION_NAME||' UPDATE INDEXES';
       END IF;
       CLOSE cur;    
   END LOOP;
END;
```

When you run this procedure the first time you may get an `ORA-14758: Last partition in the range section cannot be dropped`
In this case do

```
alter table MY_TABLE set interval ();
alter table MY_TABLE DROP PARTITION ...;
alter table MY_TABLE set INTERVAL(INTERVAL '1' DAY);
```

BTW, why do you make subpartitions by hour? I don't see any reason for it. 
I fear you misuse `TARGET_TIME`, `TARGET_DATE` and `TARGET_HOUR`. Note, **every** `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` value contains date **and** time component.  Use simple partitions, technically it would be the same but maintenance will be easier. Define table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE
   (    TARGET_TIME TIMESTAMP (6), 
    MY_ID NUMBER(10,0), 
    MY_INDEX NUMBER(10,0), 
    MY_STATUS NUMBER(10,0)
   ) 
  TABLESPACE MYTABLESPACE
  PARTITION BY RANGE (TARGET_TIME) INTERVAL (INTERVAL '1' HOUR) 
 (PARTITION "DEFAULT_20170101"  VALUES LESS THAN (TIMESTAMP '2017-01-01 00:00:00');
```

In such case procedure from above would be much simpler:

```
PROCEDURE MaintainPartitions(givenTime IN TIMESTAMP DEFAULT LOCALTIMESTAMP) IS 

    CURSOR TabParts IS
    SELECT TABLE_NAME, PARTITION_NAME, HIGH_VALUE
    FROM ALL_TAB_PARTITIONS part
    WHERE OWNER = 'MY_SCHEMA'
        AND TABLE_NAME = 'MY_TABLE'
    ORDER BY PARTITION_POSITION;

    highValue TIMESTAMP;

BEGIN
    FOR aPart IN TabParts LOOP
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN :ret := '||aPart.HIGH_VALUE||'; END;' 
          USING OUT highValue;
      IF highValue < givenTime - INTERVAL '10' HOUR THEN
          EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE '||aPart.TABLE_NAME||' DROP PARTITION '||aPart.PARTITION_NAME||' UPDATE INDEXES';
      END IF;
   END LOOP;
END;
```